# RDBMS design patterns for nested relationships

Tags: sql-server, database-design, nested

I have a data structure with a nested relationship.  What design patterns can be used to define the relationship in a relational database (SQL Server)?

Here's an example of the data structure represented in JSON:

```
Topic:
{
  applicationId: 2,
  name: 'test',
  recipients: [
    {
      id: 1,
      transports: [
        {
          id: 1,
          templateId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          templateId: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      transports: [
        {
          id: 1,
          templateId: 4,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  startTime: null,
}
```

As you can see, the relationship is one-to-many from `Topic -> Recipient -> Transport` but the relationship from `Transport -> Recipient` is dependent on the `Recipient -> Topic` association.

Currently I am defining the relationship with a single join table:

```
CREATE TABLE topics_recipients_transports
(
  id          INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  topicId     INT NOT NULL REFERENCES topics,
  recipientId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES recipients,
  transportId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES transports,
  templateId  INT NOT NULL REFERENCES templates
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX topics_recipients_transports_unique
  ON topics_recipients_transports (topicId, recipientId, transportId);
```

This approach seems the simplest but also requires significant application logic to create the nested data structure be grouping the rows by each Id.

An alternative approach I came up with would be:

```
CREATE TABLE topics_recipients
(
  id          INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  topicId     INT NOT NULL REFERENCES topics,
  recipientId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES recipients,
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX topics_recipients_uniqueON topics_recipients (topicId, recipientId);

CREATE TABLE recipients_transports
(
  id                 INT           IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  topicsRecipientsId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES topics_recipients,
  transportId        INT NOT NULL REFERENCES transports,
  config             NVARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX recipients_transports_uniqueON recipients_transports (topicsRecipientsId, transportId);

CREATE TABLE transports_templates
(
  id                     INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  recipientsTransportsId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES recipients_transports,
  templateId             INT NOT NULL REFERENCES transports
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX transports_templates_uniqueON transports_templates (recipientsTransportsId, templateId);
```

Is there a better design pattern that I am missing that would simplify the application logic to return

Comment: Why not keep it normalized? Creating 4 tables and query using joins. Did you find performance issues with that? Or is it just about being able to query data in simpler way? It's not hard even with normalized design.

Comment: I'm trying to normalize it.  The relationship of transport to recipient also depends on the topic.  So a simple join table of transportId, recipientId doesn't work because that relationship is only valid within the context of a specific topicId.  That's why I have that 3-way join table.